# Machine learning Multi Class Classification results are too good to be true?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, multiclass-classification

Hello guys I hope you're all doing great.
I am currently working on a multi-class prediction model applied to trading. I am tryng to predict the market 24 H trend.  so I can take position ( Long, Short or hold last position). I used scikit-learn's RandomForrsts. My target is composed of -1 ; 0 ; 1. My features matrix is pretty large and mostly composed of many trading indicators. 1510 dimensions

My rolling backtests of portfolio gives spectacular results. Maybe too good to be true. that's why I tried to plot the accuracy scores during the backtest period. it's seems quite good but nothing extraordinary. I tried to plot the score for you guys.
[accuracy score of the successive tranied model during backtest period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkBOi.png)

Do you think that there's a target-leakage problem or some other kind of problem or it's just good as it is ?
[RandomForrest based portfolio performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSnU7.png)

below you'ill find code snipet that does the rolling backtests

```
def backtest_glissant(x_matrix, target, rolling_window, train_depth, test_depth):
scores = []

x_matrix.sort_index()

features = x_matrix.columns
target_ = target

x = df_final.loc[:, features]
x = x.sort_index()

y = df_final.loc[:, target_]
y = y.sort_index()

data = df_final.loc[:, features]
data = data.sort_index()


x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index)
y.index = pd.to_datetime(y.index)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

start_date = x.index[0]
end_date = x.index[0]

last_date = x.index[-1]

compteur = 0

train_depth = timedelta(days=train_depth)
test_depth = timedelta(test_depth)
rolling_window = timedelta(days=rolling_window + 1 )
#rain_depth = timedelta(days=train_depth)

end_date = start_date + train_depth
while end_date < last_date:

    

    x_train = x[start_date:end_date]
    y_train = y[start_date:end_date]

    # Fixer les valeurs des hyperparamètres à tester
    param_grid = {'max_depth':[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],'n_estimators':[10,20, 30, 40, 50]}
    #'max_depth':[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    score = 'f1_macro'

    # Créer desforets aleatoires avec recherche d'hyperparamètre par validation croisée
    clf = model_selection.GridSearchCV( 
        ensemble.RandomForestClassifier( random_state = 0), # un regression forrets aléatoires
        param_grid,     # hyperparamètres à tester
        cv=5,           # nombre de folds de validation croisée
        scoring=score   # score à optimiser
    )

    clf.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())

    n_est = clf.best_params_['n_estimators']
    mx_depth = clf.best_params_['max_depth']
    
    rdm = RandomForestClassifier( n_estimators=n_est, max_depth=mx_depth,random_state=0)

    rdm.fit(x_train,y_train.values.ravel())

    x_test = x[end_date : end_date + test_depth]
    y_test = y[end_date : end_date + test_depth]
    rdm.predict(x_test)
    scores.append([end_date,rdm.score(x_test,y_test)])
    predictions = pd.DataFrame(rdm.predict(x_test), columns = ['prediction'], index = y_test.index)
    predictions = predictions.sort_index() 
    if compteur == 0:

        cumul_predictions = predictions.copy()
    else:
        cumul_predictions = cumul_predictions.append(predictions, ignore_index = False)
        cumul_predictions = cumul_predictions[~cumul_predictions.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

    star_date = start_date  + rolling_window
    end_date = end_date + rolling_window
    compteur = compteur + 1 
return cumul_predictions, scores
```

Comment: Maybe overfitting? Did you try one of those cross-validation methods?

Comment: Yes I tried cross_validation methods to get the best two hyperparameters (max_depth, n_estimators). One Question, is it possible to get overfitting on the test set ? the model seems to do quite good on test sets

Comment: Are you splitting the test set? The test set is considered as unseen data. So, your model shouldn't look at the test set even when you're optimizing hyperparameters (cross-validation). Are you sure that the test set is not a part of cross-validated data?

Comment: Hello , @SeljukGülcan yes I am pretty sure 100% that the test set is not a part of cross-Validation data

Comment: I edited my question to add code snippet that does the work. thank you guys !